Codeception: Symfony fixtures are not being autowired
I have a pretty simple repository test case:
class AmaRepositoryCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->loadFixtures(AmaFixture::class);
    }

    public function testMe(FunctionalTester $I): void
    {
        $result = $I->grabService(AmaRepository::class)->getByUid(1);
        $I->assertEquals([2, 3], $result);
    }
}

But it happened so AmaFixture has a service injected into it, so I'm getting an error

[ArgumentCountError] Too few arguments to function
App\DataFixtures\AmaFixture::__construct(), 0 passed in
/application/vendor/codeception/module-doctrine/src/Codeception/Module/Doctrine.php
on line 727 and exactly 1 expected

yet, it works if I run php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
here is my Functional.suite.yml
actor: FunctionalTester
namespace: Tests
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - Tests\Support\Helper\Functional
        - Symfony:
              app_path: 'src'
            
        - Doctrine:
            depends: Symfony
            cleanup: true
    step_decorators: ~      

Symfony 6.1, Codeception 5.0

This is because the Doctrine Codeception module simply calls the constructor of the fixtures class without providing any parameters, i.e. $fixtureInstance = new $fixture(); (unlike the fixtures-load command which does use the service container and correctly autowires dependencies).
A possible workaround is to use "setter injection" so the dependency is loaded via a setter instead of the constructor. Note that in your test you would need to manually call this setter with the required dependency, e.g. via $I->grabService(...) as this is not done automatically.

hi! I have figured out the grabService solutionm so far, thought there might be a conventional way. thanks anyway.
